# How to get a list of random numbers that should be unique

Tags: c#, random, unique

In C#, I want to have the list of 5 random numbers, that should contain unique values from 1 to 5? How can I achieve that?

for example: 1,3,2,5,4 or 2,5,1,3,4

i.e. The list must contains 5 random numbers that should be having the numbers from 1 to 5

Comment: random values != randomly shuffled unique values

Comment: See also: http://ericlippert.com/2013/04/15/producing-permutations-part-one/

Comment: Have you tried anything? Have you done any research? The content of this question implies no.

Answer (score 4):

```
Random rnd = new Random();
var list = Enumerable.Range(1, 5).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called [shuffling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). The Fisher–Yates shuffle I linked let you do that in linear time, that is about the best you can get.

To do that in C#, you can even implement an extension method, that will look like :

```
    public static Random rand = new Random();
    public static List<T> Shuffle<T>(this List<T> original)
    {
        List<T> lst = new List<T>(original);
        for (int i = lst.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int j = rand.Next(0, i + 1);
            T tmp = lst[j];
            lst[j] = lst[i];
            lst[i] = tmp;
        }
        return lst;
    }
```

and then call it with:

```
var shuffled = lst.Shuffle();
```

Comment: `rand.Next(0,i + 1)` can produce `i+1`, if it's the first loop, that means `j = lst.Count` and the `lst[j]` will throw an `ArgumentOutOfRangeException`?

Comment: @KingKing No it can't. The second argument is *exclusive*.

Comment: @KingKin "maxValue : The exclusive upper bound of the random number returned." So no, it can't because the second argument of Next is exclusive while the first one is inclusive

Comment: OK, didn't read the document.

Comment: Problem with your code is that you have a static method that isn't thread-safe.